# google app engine as an image server

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, coldfusion, lucee

I have a compute instance on Google Cloud running a web app written in Coldfusion. I would like to leverage the great app engine functionality that Google offers for the upload, storage, modification and, most importantly, secure serving of images and files from buckets in Google Cloud Storage.

Is it possible to make a request from my compute instance to the app engine that will reply with the fully signed URL of the requested image?

I was assuming that if I had uploaded foo.jpg to the bucket and then could request that from app engine I could then use the returned URL as my img src. I would have all image names saved on Cloud SQL with their appropriate bucket address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the ImageService rather than appengine, it does exactly what you need:

1. you store the image bytes in a bucket
2. build a serving URL using the ImageService
3. clients use the serving URL to request the
   image from Google's image servers

In java it looks like this:

```
//whatever your file path is   
String fullGcsName "/gs/bucket_name/file_name.jpg";
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(fullGcsName);
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
String servingUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(options);
```

When the client requests the 'servingUrl' sizing options can be added if you want to serve as a thumbnail for example.

Comment: Java documentation for this service is here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/images/

Comment: Hi Steve. 

1. Do the serving URLs come in the secure format from this?
2. How can I run this request from compute engine? If I'm not mistaken, all of this is for app engine - not quite got time to transfer all the code at the moment!

Comment: @Richard Firth, what do you mean by "secure format"? Also, ImageService is available from App Engine only. But you wanted to use App Engine for this right? And return the url to your app running on Compute Engine?

Comment: ImageService is part of AppEngine standard environment. You don't need to write server code to serve images though, the ImageService will do that for you. I'm not sure what you mean by secure format..... The URLs are served over https, and they aren't easy to read, for example: 

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gxSQZgziZ_EDhnR663vE_2PBgFOAVCtxCEtuZFnWCb4IO940CclTlQqRL0zDDpb2uTVkWHNR7MuN2qIel7kc0Om0Nsp1LIVPOIU=s900

Comment: I ended up going with this using a slightly clunky cfhttp method. Even in Lucee 5 this is pretty slow!! I would guess that doing this in Java would be quicker, but don't know how to implement